# Basecontrol Page.LoadComplete -= Page_LoadComplete raises Object ref error if child control is loaded more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling

I have a base control:

```
public partial class BaseControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Page.LoadComplete += Page_LoadComplete;
    }

    protected virtual void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.LoadComplete -= Page_LoadComplete;
    }
}
```

I then have a control that derives from this

```
public partial class MyChildControl : BaseControl
```

The problem I have is that if I load `MyChildControl` more than once then I get an object ref error on `Page.LoadComplete -= Page_LoadComplete;` in `BaseControl`. I sort of understand why but I have 2 questions:

1. Shouldn't each `MyChildControl` reference it's own version of `BaseControl` which in turn registers it's own `PageLoadComplete`?
2. How can I check to see if it is not null? I can't seem to do `!= null`.

EDIT: It seems that `Page` is null and checking `Page != null` resolves the issue but I still don't understand how `Page` is null.

Comment: `Page_LoadComplete` can't be null, it's just a delegate created for methog Page_LoadComplete. So i think Page in `Page.LoadComplete` may be null or page has custom logic for adding handler to event LoadComplete and has ref error there.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the case as checking `Page != null` seems to sort it. I can only assume I am nulling the page somewhere then .. Will look.

Comment: @Nikolay - Can you post your comment as an answer please. This resolved my issue albeit leaving me a little confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page_LoadComplete` can't be null, it's just a delegate created for methog `Page_LoadComplete`. So i think Page in `Page.LoadComplete` may be null or page has custom logic for adding handler to event LoadComplete and has ref error there